# Braintree - Transaction is successful even though fraud returns "Decline"

Tags: ruby, braintree

I submit a transaction with a valid card but I make it trigger a "Decline" from RiskData by making a lot of transactions with that card quickly. The problem is that it still makes the transaction successful and submits it for settlement even when RiskData returns "Decline".

Here is what Braintree has [regarding a "Decline" RiskData](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/javascript+php/guides/fraud-tools):

> 'Decline' - The transaction was declined due to fraud risk.

Is this how it's supposed to function? Should I change the configuration to make it reject a transaction for "Decline"?

Here is some reference:

```
#<Braintree::SuccessfulResult transaction:#<Braintree::Transaction id: "xxxxx"...>
#<RiskData id: "xxxxxxxxx", decision: "Decline">
```

Comment: I work at Braintree. Is this happening in the production or sandbox environment? In Sandbox, we don't act on the risk decision, so this is expected behavior if you aren't using the [fraud rejection card number](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/javascript+ruby/reference/general/testing#fraud-information). This shouldn't happen in production.

Comment: This is in the sandbox. So the transaction will be rejected in production if risk data returns "Decline"?

Comment: Will the transaction be rejected or approved (in production) if risk data returns "Review"?

Comment: In production, "Decline" RiskData will cause transactions to be rejected; "Review" RiskData will not. It's unlikely you'll ever see a status of "Review" in production unless you obtain your own merchant ID with Kount directly and set your own rules to trigger this response.

Comment: @agf Great, thanks for the info! You can answer the question to make it easier to find for others who are wondering.

Comment: I've reposted the content from from my comments as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<sub>I work at Braintree. If you have more questions, please [reach out to our support team](https://support.braintreepayments.com/).</sub>

In Sandbox, Braintree doesn't act on the risk decision, so this is expected behavior if you aren't using the [fraud rejection card number](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/javascript+ruby/reference/general/testing#fraud-information).

In production, "Decline" RiskData will cause transactions to be rejected; "Review" RiskData will not. It's unlikely you'll ever see a status of "Review" in production unless you obtain your own merchant ID with Kount directly and set your own rules to trigger this response.